# Why/how does Luke happen to land on Dagobah so close to Yoda's home?

Tags: star-wars

In *The Empire Strikes Back,* Luke Skywalker travels to Dagobah and receives training from Yoda.

But how does he know where on Dagobah Yoda resides? Per Wookieepedia, [Dagobah is 14,410 kilometers in diameter](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dagobah), making it slightly larger than Earth. In the scene where Luke reaches Dagobah, he says to R2-D2 that there are no signs of cities or technology, but massive lifeforms. He then seemingly descends into the planet's atmosphere at random, loses control and crash lands into a swamp.

Luke then proceeds to transfer equipment and supplies from the X-Wing fighter to dry land to make camp. Soon after, Yoda wanders into Luke's camp. Such a planet would have a surface area of about 600,000,000 square kilometers. It seems quite fortuitous that Luke just happened to crash land right next door to Yoda's home!

**Is there any explanation in the canon as to how or why Luke is able to, seemingly at random, crash land within walking distance of Yoda's home?**

Comment: The how is easy enough. He ploughs it into the ground at three hundred MPH

Comment: I always assumed Yoda brought him down using the force.  The scene where Yoda lifts the X-Wing out of the swamp was, to me, Yoda admitting this to Luke and the audience

Comment: Let's not forget he was instructed to go to Dagobah by a ghost he conversed with at the brink of death. It's reasonably conceivable he was further guided on his trip. Or somehow just knew where to go. It's Star Wars. No surprises in happenstance.